# float left div 100% width

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs within a container with each of their widths set at 100%. if I float them all left they will stack on top of each other. What I would like for them to do is float next to each other horizontally. Changing the width of the div to a fixed width works fine. How can I achieve this? Thank you for your help and time.

html

```
<div id="scroller">
  <div id="slide-container">
    <div class="slide" style="background-color:yellow;">
    </div>
    
    <div class="slide" style="background-color:orange;">
    </div>
    
    <div class="slide" style="background-color:red;">
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
body, html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#scroller {
  min-width:100%;
  height:400px;
  background-color:blue;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#slide-container {
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  left:0;
  white-space:nowrap;
  font-size:0;
}

.slide {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;    
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  float:left;
}
```

https://codepen.io/justinhdevelopment/pen/bGexaJy codepen example of problem

Comment: Do your want your divs to stack horizontally and fill up the entire space? Please explain what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes each div is 100% of the container and I would like them to stack horizontally.

Comment: I have updated the pen to show the problem 
https://codepen.io/justinhdevelopment/pen/bGexaJy

Comment: If you set the width of a child element 100%, then it will take 100% space of the parent container's width. However, if you set the width of each child 100%, they will just overflow the parent container.

Comment: Yes overflow will be hidden

Comment: So you want to create something like a slideshow in which each slide takes 100%?

Comment: Yessir that is what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am updating my answer. Kindly check if it can work for you and make the necessary changes if needed.

Comment: Okay I will look into it. Thank you very much Praneet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some use of `flex` and `overflow-x` to make your desired effect. You can further make changes as per your need-

```css
body, html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow: none;
}

#slide-container {
  height:400px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.slide {
  height:400px;
  min-width:100%;
}
#scroller {
  min-width:100%;
  height:400px;
  background-color:blue;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="scroller">
  <div id="slide-container">
    <div class="slide" style="background-color:yellow;">
    </div>
    
    <div class="slide" style="background-color:orange;">
    </div>
    
    <div class="slide" style="background-color:red;">
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need .slide to be 100% width so it stretches to fit #scroller. Thank you though, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: If you set the width 100% then you will not be able to achieve the horizontal stacking effect. Do you want your all `.slide` to stretch equally to fit the outer `slide-container` so that you can see three equal sections?

Comment: The only way to have 100% width is to use a fixed size?

Comment: I want each div to be the same size as #scroller and stack horizontally

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding what you are looking for correctly what you are looking for is using a flex display in your parent div:

```
  #slide-container {
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  left:0;
  white-space:nowrap;
  font-size:0;
  display: flex;
}
```

Take a look at this for further reference:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: I have updated the codepen with slide-container display set to flex. The problem is the size of the div no longer is 100% of the parent container #scroller https://codepen.io/justinhdevelopment/pen/bGexaJy

Comment: i also will have overflow hidden so the other 2 divs will not show unless i position #slide-container more left or more right using left: or right:

Comment: I opened your codepen, and so just to be clear you are not wanting to see any blue onscreen and you want your three divs to cover the screen equally?

Comment: Yeah, if you add negative left value to #slide-container you should see orange instead of blue

Comment: Okay, just remove your left:-20px and then it is the completely covering the parent container. By adding the -20 you are not changing the size of it you are just moving it.

Comment: I want slide-container to contain 3 divs each div is 100% of the container #scroller and have all 3 side by side horizontally so when I use left on the #slide-container it slides all 3 to the left. If there is no left, yes you will see the first 100% width div.. this is true. I should be able to put left:-50px on the slide-container this will move all 3 divs to the left so you will see 50px of the next div.

Comment: Ah I am understanding more now what you want based on your comment in the above answer. If you are wanting each div to be the same size as #scroller then what you could do is just give each child div a separate class name with left: 30% o so in the first, left: 120p% etc in the second and so on...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224237/discussion-between-justin-harris-and-mamdlv).